# Using "champion" as a verb

Tags: meaning, verbs

John McCarthy, Father of Artificial Intelligence, just passed away. I just read an article about him, which stated that

> he **championed** mathematical logic for Artificial Intelligence.

I am not sure of the meaning of *champion*, although I have seen it used in several similar occasions. I just looked it up and assume that it means to defend or to support.

My intuition is that *champion* could be the very word we should think of in the first place in this context. Is that true? Could any other word be a better alternative here?

Comment: It's an adjective in the Midlands (UK) — "that's champion".

Comment: "Champion *verb*: champion something to fight for or speak in support of a group of people or a belief" — [Ofxord Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/champion_2). No research done, voting to close as general reference.

Comment: Given that (at this date, more than four years after it was asked) the question has drawn 8973 views, I think it ought to be grandfathered past close-vote referendums that challenge its lack of research and its open-ended request for "a better alternative."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To champion something is to promote it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. To 'champion' in this context, means to be its defender and protector.  In your example, John McCarthy being the champion of mathematical logic for AI means he argued in favor of that approach to achieving AI.

Answer (score 3):

The previous two posters are right. *Champion* is first recorded as a verb in Shakespeare’s ‘Macbeth’, although with a different meaning from that in your example. It was first used figuratively in the sense ‘maintain the cause of, stand up for, uphold, support, back, defend, advocate’ in 1844. (Source: OED)

Comment: Is that really a different meaning from the example above? It seems to be *exactly* what John McFarthy did for AI (except, probably, for physically defending it, but I'm not even sure about that).

Comment: No, it isn't. It was the use in 'Macbeth' that was different. There it meant 'to challenge to a contest; to bid defiance to'. That meaning is now obsolete.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry I misread your post (I missed the "in 1844" part, interpreting it as "It was *first* used figuratively.")

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

1. With the exception of this line in *Macbeth* III.1:

   > come, fate, into the lists 
   >   And **champion** me to the utterance

   the word *champion* is only used as a noun by Shakespeare.
2. With one exception¹, *champion* as a noun in Shakespeare **always** has the clear meaning of “supporter or representative in a cause”.

With all due respect to Dr. Johnson’s interpretation of *champion me* as “fight *against* me”, is it not then possible that Macbeth is calling to fate to be his strong *representative* in his endeavours, despite the witches’ predictions? That is, “Come into the lists as my champion, and fight against whatever forces [Fortune, etc.] might oppose you.”

¹ The exception: In *Venus and Adonis*, Adonis is in one place referred to as “her [meaning Venus’s] champion” when Venus tries to compel Adonis to mount her. The metaphor here would appear to be Adonis = knight, Venus = knight’s steed, so that “her champion” = “her rider”.

Comment: I think not. Macbeth has just been gnawing on the sisters' prophesy that Banquo is destined to father a line of kings which will wrench the scepter from Macbeth's hand. Fate is thus the champion of Banquo's line, and it is in that capacity that Macbeth challenges fate.

Comment: Isn't this going at a tangent to OP's context? Or at least, much farther than it warrants? :)

Answer (score 0):

To "Tout" something ?

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tout):

> - to talk about (something or someone) as being very good, effective, skillful, etc.
> - to try to persuade people to buy your goods or services
> - to buy tickets for an event and resell them at a much higher price

Comment: Are you aware that this is a public board? You are dramatically increasing the amount of spam to your inbox by posting your email address here.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен - I was about to remove it. Is that not [the protocol](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37956/allow-users-to-put-their-e-mail-in-posts)?

Comment: Feel free to edit it out. I hadn't seen that post. I wouldn't say that that post offers consensus, as very few people have seen it, but I agree that the address is noise.